# How do I update my software and updates?

Tags: skype

When I try to update my Software and Updates i get this message,

```
W:Failed to fetch http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/precise/steam/i18n/Translation-en  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection [IP: 24.140.0.87 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

My Internet connection is fine and I don't know what else could be causing it. I'm trying to install skype and nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Get update software list, enter:

> $ sudo apt-get update

Update software(s) i.e. apply updates and patches on Ubuntu Linux

> $ sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Ok your issue dealing with two different type of problems.

Issue 1 : may be there might be issue with your update server. Open Update Manager settings and then change your mirror to main mirror or best mirror from your location. You will see that option there.

Issue 2:  You have something wrong in your sources.list file so , If you can give us your sources.list file then we can help to fix your issue.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enter this in the terminal:

```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and also this in the terminal:

```
   sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and this also:

```
   sudo apt-get clean
```

and the you can update and upgrade, and it might work fine this way.